Mostrar imagen usando ACF Shortcode
Estoy usando elementor pro essential + ACF. Usando la opción de shortcode puedo listar los meta campos que he creado en ACF sin problema (siempre que sean textos). Lo que ahora deseo es mostrar una imagen del campo "banner_del_curso", para ello estoy llamo al shortcode: ver configuración
[acf field="banner_del_curso"]

Sin embargo solo me muestra el ID de la imagen. He leido diferentes alternativas que sugieren insertar un código "php", actualmente estoy usando este:
<?php 
$image = get_field('banner_del_curso');
$size = 'full'; // (thumbnail, medium, large, full or custom size)
if( $image ) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
}

Sin éxito. Me lo sugirió esta web: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/
¿Podrían indicarme que estoy haciendo mal? o ¿Qué sugerencias me podrían dar para poder mostrar imagenes usando el widget "shortcode" de elementor ver imagen

1/ el shortcode "acf" sólo funciona con/ renderiza campos de texto, de ahí que veas sólo el ID. el shortcode por lo general está desactivado debido a que cualquier user con capabilities de "edit_post" puede exfiltrar datos tan sólo conociendo el nombre del campo.

2/ elementor pro te permite elegir un "origen dinámico" para las imágenes y ya trae soporte para acf v5+ lo podes activar haciendo rollover sobre el placeholder del elemento imagen y eligiendo origen dinamico, acf, custom field etc

3/ el shortcode acf así como está te da siempre el mismo número? get_field intenta averiguar el contexto, pero si es un template hay que ayudarle pasandole el id de post/cpt o usar get_field_from_term . es decir que para armar un shortcode haría falta saber si está ligado a un custom post type o una taxonomía

@aloMalbarez Muchas gracias por tus respuestas e intentar ayudarme. Mis comentarios a continuación:
1/ Correcto acf solo renderiza campos de texto, pero leí que usando un snippet podría hacer que jale una imagen. Yo creería que está activo porque sino no podría usar los demás shortcodes.

@aloMalbarez 2/ Elementor Pro permite usar las etiquetas dinámicas, pero en las nuevas cuentas con suscripcion "essential" no muestra la opción de ACF, ya me lo confirmó el soporte técnico de elementor y también lo dice en su web, justo por ello estoy tratando opciones adicionales.

@aloMalbarez 3/ El ID de la imagen que me arroja es simepre el mismo. Esto de ayudarlo pasándole el id post lo leí por algún lado, pero no le he realizado. Uso un template creado en elementor. ¿Me podrías ayudar editando el código php para usar el get_field_from_term

Continuemos el debate en el chat.

puedes probar con otroas funciones aparte de wp_get_attachment_image(), como estas otras: wp_get_attachment_url($id,$size), wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, $size) o también wp_get_attachment_metadata($id) y a ver que te regresan

El shortcode por defecto no tiene la capacidad de renderizar imagenes, pero podemos crear uno personalizado.
Para que funcione debemos de tomar en cuenta 2 cosas, lo primero es conocer el id del field al que queremos llamar y lo segundo es conocer el id del post al que queremos llamar.
Con eso en mente podemos construir un shortcode que haga el trabajo, por ejemplo.
add_shortcode( 'get_acf_image', 'get_acf_image_callback' );

function get_acf_image_callback( $atts ){

    // Obtenemos el field de ACF
    $field = $atts['field'];

    // Obtenemos el id del post al que esta ligado
    // el metacampo de acf
    $post_id = $atts['post_id'];
    if ( empty( $post_id ) ) :
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
    endif;

    // Obtenemos el tamaño de la imagen
    $size = $atts['size'];
    if ( empty( $size ) ) :
        $size = 'full';
    endif;

    $image = get_field( $field, $post_id );
    if ( $image ) :

        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image, $size );
        return '<img src="' . $image_url . '">';

    endif;

    return;
}

Esto imprimirá una imagen según el id que le enviamos, la sentencia:
$post_id = $atts['post_id'];
if ( empty( $post_id ) ) :
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
endif;

Lo que hace es llamar el id del post que tiene el metadato, si no le enviamos nada obtendremos el id del post actual, esto es útil si lo usaras dentro de un loop o dentro de un single, sin embargo, fuera de ello si debes especificar el id del post, si no obtendrá el actual.
Con eso en mente ahora deberías poder llamar a
[get_acf_image field="banner_del_curso" post_id="" size="full"]

Esto debería funcionar bien dentro de un single o un loop. Pero si estas fuera de uno deberas especificar el post id del que quieres obtener el metadato, por ejemplo:
[get_acf_image field="banner_del_curso" post_id="1" size="full"]

Siempre verifica que el ID del field y el ID del post si estas fuera de un loop sea correcto, de lo contrario simplemente no devolverá nada.
Aqui los enlaces que use de referencia.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/
No he probado esto así que no estoy 100% seguro de si funcionara, hazme saber en los comentarios si no llega a funcionar.

te agradezco la gentiliza de tomarte tu tiempo y responder a mi consulta. Te comento que pude solucionarlo pegando el php que daba la página de ACF y con la ayuda de "Code Snippets" pegue dicho php y en la manera de mostrar le puse "shortcode". Finalmente ingresé el shortcode creado en la parte donde quería mostrar dicha imagen. Gracias nuevamente.
